# How to alert a java script object in its string representation format ?

Tags: javascript

How to alert a java script object in its string representation format ? 
For example, If there is a variable like this :

```
var a = {1:"abc",2:"xyz"};
```

How it can be printed out like below format using alert(a) or something like that ?

```
1 : abc
2 : xyz
```

Comment: See here https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Debugging_JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.stringify will convert your javascript object to String. Then your can replace "," with "\n" to show each field in new line. If you want to remove "{" then you can do .replace("{","")

```
var a ={x:"sdfd"}
alert(JSON.stringify(a).replace(",","\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
var a = {1:"abc",2:"xyz"};
var s = "";
for(var i in a){
  s = s + "\n" + i + ":" + " " + a[i];
}
alert(s);
```

Or

```
alert(JSON.stringify(a));
```

If you want to debug objects in javascript, you must see to [console.log](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api) )) try it!